# Mail server connection failed

Tags: email, grails

I'm developing an application using `Grails 3.3.11`, using `Spring security plugin` and [mail plugin](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/mail) in the forgot password. I send to the user an email with a link to access it to be able to reset the password, this is already made in the Spring security plugin all I have to do is to configure the email in `application.yml`.
The problem I'm facing in the development when the user resets succssufully the password if I tried to reset the password again I got an error related to the `Mail server`, something is closing or resetting the server connection but I can't figure what is it ,I telnet the mail server and everything responding, to make everything works fine I have to restrat the application, here is the error:

```
    org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:433)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:346)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:341)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender$send$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at grails.plugins.mail.MailMessageBuilder.sendMessage(MailMessageBuilder.groovy:130)
    at grails.plugins.mail.MailService.sendMail(MailService.groovy:55)
    at grails.plugins.mail.MailService.sendMail(MailService.groovy:59)
    at grails.plugins.mail.MailService$sendMail.call(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:124)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:92)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2349)
    ... 195 common frames omitted
```

here are the configurations in the `application.yml`:

```
  mail:
         default:
                from: 'info@domain.com'
                host: "mail.privateemail.com"
                port :  587 
                username: "bbb@domain.com"
                password : "password"
                props : ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
                "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"587",
               "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
               "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
```

Comment: have you tried `"mail.smtp.starttls.enable":"true"` ? please check out different configs: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html

Comment: @Michal_Szulc added it but still getting the error

Comment: Is it a private email server? Try a well known email server as gmail and check out if everything works as expected. Maybe it's a misconfiguration of your email server?

Comment: Did you get this working ?

Comment: @SaifAsif  unfortunately still getting occasionally this error and I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles here, what worked for me are the following configurations

`application.yml`

```yaml
  mail:
    host: mail.privateemail.com
    port: 587
    username: somewhere@somewhat.com
    password: abc123
    properties:
      mail:
        transport:
          protocol: smtp
        smtp:
          port: 587
          auth: true
          starttls:
            enable: true
            required: true
```

And then you inject and use the `JavaMailSender` as below

```java
    @Autowired
    private final JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    sendEmail() {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        // ... set to and from address
        javaMailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);
    }
```

Comment: tried what you mentioned in the `application.yml` but still getting occasionally the connection rest error